# pointer vs value receivers in Go

Tags: go, pointers, struct, interface

I've encountered a rather curious situation in Go. Consider the code below:

```golang
type reader struct {
    finished bool
}

func (r *reader) Read() {
    fmt.Println("reading...")
    r.finished = true
}

func main() {
    r := reader{} // notice that r is not a pointer to a reader struct
    r.Read() // works just fine
    fmt.Println(r.finished) // true
}
```

What I think about the code above is that the method

```golang
func (r *reader) Read() {...}
```

is the same as

```golang
func Read(r *reader) {...}
```

so when I call the `.Read()` method in a non-pointer `reader` type go automatically does something like this:

```golang
r := reader{}
(&r).Read() // something like Read(&r)
```

Correct me if I'm wrong since this is merely my deduction.

But my actual question is that why the same scenario does not work if I try to declare `Reader` interface type with the concrete type being `reader` and the concrete value being an instance of the `reader` struct, like below:

```golang
type Reader interface {
    Read()
}

type reader struct {
    finished bool
}

func (r *reader) Read() {...}

func main() {
    var r Reader = reader{} // compile error
    r.Read()
}
```

The compile error above states:
`cannot use reader{} (value of type reader) as Reader value in variable declaration: reader does not implement Reader (method Read has pointer receiver)`

Can anyone explain what's exactly going on under the hood? Why are the behaviors different for structs and interfaces?

Comment: Regarding the first code example, your deduction is correct: `r.Read()` is __shorthand__ for `(&r).Read()`. This is allowed because the variable `r` is __addressable__. However note that just because `r.Read()` is __shorthand__ for `(&r).Read()` that does not mean that `reader` _implements_ `Read`, it does NOT, only `*reader` _implements_ `Read`. I mean if `reader` _implemented_ `Read` what would be the point of the __shorthand__? Why would Go have to do `(&r).Read()` if `Read()` was _implemented_ by `reader`?

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks for your kind answer, it was clear and insightful.

Comment: The official language spec explains this pretty well too.